# Grails, CI in Jenkins taking 4 hours to build

Tags: grails, jenkins, cobertura

We have upgraded from Grails 2.2.X to 2.4.3 in version 2.3.X Grails went to a fork execution.  We have set that up in our development environment and it is working well.  We check into Jenkins and we seem to get build and test times of about 4 hours where running locally it is minutes.  I am making a assumption that the memory settings for the fork are being ignored and causing the builds to take unacceptably long.  Previous builds were 25 to 30 minutes depending on load.  Other applications not upgraded are still within minutes for building.

Jenkins version is 1.51, Grails 2.4.3, JVM 1.7.

In our BuildConfig.groovy file we have these settings

```
forkConfig = [maxMemory: 4096, minMemory: 512, debug: false, maxPerm: 2048]

grails.project.fork = [
   test: forkConfig, // configure settings for the test-app JVM
   run: forkConfig, // configure settings for the run-app JVM
   war: forkConfig, // configure settings for the run-war JVM
   console: forkConfig // configure settings for the Swing console JVM
]
```

Wondering how would I get Jenkins to use those.  Our build environment in Jenkins is set to JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m

Everything seems to be ignored.

We are also running Cobertura coverage reports and they are reporting areas of code that are not being executed within our unit and Integration tests, which I know that they being tested.

Any ideas on what to look at and pursue would be helpful.

Comment: What command are you using in jenkins for the build?  As for cobertura what version are you running?

Comment: The command for the Grails build is clean refresh-dependencies "test-app --stacktrace --verbose --coverage -xml"

Comment: Cobertura is Cobertura Plugin 1.8

Comment: You can't use that version of the grails coverage plugin with forked execution are you using grailsw or the grails plugin for Jenkins?

Comment: Grails Plugin for Jenkins, I am assuming when you say grails coverage plugin = you mean Cobertura Plugin,  What is the alternative?

Comment: http://grails.org/plugin/code-coverage This plugin

Comment: Updated to this plugin same results. Running version test      ':code-coverage:2.0.3-3'